# Fragments not opaque during animation

Tags: animation, android-fragments, transparent

I have searched on stackoverflow and google but could not find a solution to a simple problem.

I have a fragment on the screen and want to make a new fragment slide in from below in such a way that the old fragment is slowly covered up during the animation until it is no more visible.

The problem I have, is that the fragment sliding in is transparent during the animation, i.e. you can see the fragment below. I want the fragment sliding in to be completely opaque. How can I achieve that?

I have already set the background of both fragments to a specific color but it did not solve the problem.

Here is my code.
Fragment sliding in:

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:padding="@dimen/std_margin"
>     android:background="@color/fragment_background" >
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

In the activity:

> ```
> FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
> ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.fade_out);
> String tag = backStack.peek();
> BaseFragment top = (BaseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
> ft.detach(top);
> String tag2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
> ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, tag2);
> backStack.push(tag2);
> ft.commit();
> ```